# Ruby subtract two string arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
array1 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"]
array2 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"]
```

"Subtract" the two arrays so the result is:

```
["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"]
```

The order of the strings doesn't matter.  The position of the elements doesn't matter.  Here is another example:

```
array1 = ["Hi", "Jimmy", "Whats", "Up"]
array2 = ["Whats", "Hi"]
SOME CODE
result = ["Jimmy", "Up"]
```

Another example:

```
array1 = ['a','a','b','b','c']
array2 = ['a','c']
SOME CODE
result = ['a','b','b']
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with more examples and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the less complex, more readable solution, If you wish to use Sets

```
require 'set'
    class Array
      def minus(values)
        values_set = Set.new values 
        reject { |e| values_set.delete(e) if values_set.include?(e) }
      end
    end
```

Usage:

```
array1 = ['a','a','b','b','c']
array2 = ['a','c']
puts array1.minus(array2)
```

EDIT:
Enhancement of @Ronan's Solution, handling the case mentioned by @Cary

```
a = ["Hi", "Jimmy", "Whats", "Up"]
b = ["Whats", "Hi"]
c = b.each.with_object(a) { |del| a.delete_at(a.index(del))}
puts c
```

Comment: If `array2 = ['a','a','c']`, `array1.minus(array2) #=> ["a", "b", "b"]`. I assume that it that case the OP wants the return value to be  `["b", "b"]`. If so, you cannot convert `array2` to a set.

Comment: I believe you want `b.each`, not `b.each_with_object`. If `a` does not contain `del` `a.index(del)` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting 2 arrays using `array1 - array2` will remove **every value** in `array1` that matches a value in `array2`. In your case, that's not what you want.

So you can add your custom `subtract()` method to the `Array` class, like this:

```
class Array
  def subtract(array)
    array.each do |val|
      if index = index(val)
        delete_at(index)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can use that method like this:

```
array1 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"]
array2 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"]
array1.subtract(array2)
puts(array1) # array1 now contains ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"]
```

Comment: This works, but has a weakness: `index` is executed once for each element of `array2`, making it O(`array1.size*array2.size`).

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @Ronan's answer but it doesn't mutate `array1`.

```
array1.difference(array2)
  #=> ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"]

['a','a','b','b','c'].difference(['a','c','d']
  #=> ["a", "b", "b"]
```

where

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

As hash lookups have nearly constant times, the computational complexity of this method is close to  O(`[array1.size, array2.size].max`).

I proposed that this method be added to the Ruby Core [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) but there has been little expressed interest in doing so. Some of the method's uses are discussed at the link.